# Regular expression in C# parse into double array

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, parsing

I'm not to good in Regular Expressions.
I have

```
string rgba = "[0.123,0.223,0.2,1]";
```

What would be the best way to covert it into double[] ?

Comment: assuming rgba strings have no spaces? (like `[0.1,  1.0,   0.5, 1 ]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
rgba.Replace("]", String.Empty)
    .Replace("[", String.Empty)
    .Split(',')
    .Select(double.Parse)
    .ToArray();
```

Or if you know that it will always start with `[` and end with `]`

```
rgba.Substring(1, rgba.Length - 2)
    .Split(',')
    .Select(double.Parse)
    .ToArray();
```

And if you don't like LINQ

```
Array.ConvertAll(rgba.Substring(1, rgba.Length - 2).Split(','), double.Parse);
```

Regex is quite expensive to use, and I wouldn't recommend it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with body:

> \d+\.\d*

The regex will match one or more digits, then a single dot, then any number of digits.