# Array::ConvertAll in managed C++

Tags: .net, arrays, parsing, c++-cli, managed

This is a continuation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532301/regular-expression-in-c-parse-into-double-array) post.

I'm trying to parse this string in managed C++:

```
String ^ rgba = "[0.09019608,0.5176471,0.9058824,1]";
cli::array<System::Double> ^ RGB = System::Array::ConvertAll<String,cli::array<System::Double> >((rgba->Substring(1,rgba->Length-2)->Split(',')),double::Parse);
```

Compiler throws me the following error:

```
Error   15  error C2770: invalid explicit generic argument(s) for 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^System::Array::ConvertAll(cli::array<TInput,1> ^,System::Converter<TInput,TOutput> ^)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified incorrect type parameters for ConvertAll. You have specified that your are converting from array of strings, to an array of arrays of doubles - it should just be from strings to doubles.

PS Trying to cram less into a single line would make it easier to read!

**Example**

```
String^ rgba = "[0.09019608,0.5176471,0.9058824,1]";

array<String^>^ values = rgba->Substring(1,rgba->Length-2)->Split(',');

Converter<String^, double>^ converter =
    gcnew Converter<String^, double>(double::Parse);

array<double>^ RGB = Array::ConvertAll(values, converter);
```

Comment: Thank you and Murry Christmas.